# csv response to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests, read.csv

I have this code:

```
import requests
import json

import pandas as pd
import io

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
```

It returns a response:

```
print(response.text)
```

> ```
> GENESIS-Tabelle: 45213-0005
> Turnover from accommodation and food services: Germany,;;;;;;;;;;;;;
> months, price types, original and adjusted data, economic;;;;;;;;;;;;;
> activities;;;;;;;;;;;;;
> Monthly statistics: accommodation a. food services;;;;;;;;;;;;;
> Germany;;;;;;;;;;;;;
> Turnover (2015=100);;;;;;;;;;;;;
> ;;Year;;;;;;;;;;;
> ;;2023;;;;;;;;;;;
> ;;Months;;;;;;;;;;;
> ;;January;February;March;April;May;June;July;August;September;October;November;December
> WZ08-55 Accommodation;;;;;;;;;;;;;
> at constant prices;BV4.1 trend;100.1;100.0;98.3;95.9;93.4;90.7;88.4;86.7;...;...;...;...
> WZ08-551 Hotels and similar accommodation;;;;;;;;;;;;;
> at constant prices;BV4.1 trend;100.6;100.5;98.8;96.4;93.9;91.2;88.9;87.3;...;...;...;...
> ```

I am able to write it to csv file. But unable to load it into pandas. What changes can be done to make it work?

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(response.text))
```

> ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line
> 3, saw 4

Comment: The first line does not have any CSV in it.

Answer (score 1):

The data that you have in response.text is not in a format that it can be parsed as a csv file. It is structured with multiple delimiters and irregular line breaks. Data seems to be separated by semicolons and some lines have more fields than others.

You will have to do

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(response.text), sep=';')

And it should work but you might have to do some changes once this works with the above statement because as I mentioned your data is not structured properly.

Answer (score 0):

panda.read_csv uses "," as default separator, so it will split each line with respect to ",". Now, you can see the number of commas are different among the lines making it impossible for parser to correctly read/split the file (into columns) and hence the error. One way is to use a different separator (here, it is likely sep = ";"). This way you can load file into data frame and later manipulate it to suite your requirement.